# Applying the use of Functions and Procedures

Tags: java, bluej

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    System.out.println("Enter a number to find the factorial of it: ");      
    number= sc.nextInt(); 
    int factor=1;
    if (number<0 && number>10)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid!! the number has to be between 1 and 10");
    }
    for( int x=1; x<=number; x++ )
    {       
      factor = factor*x;            
      System.out.println("The factorial of  "+number+" is = " +factor);
    }

 }
```

Can u check my code @TNT? tell me if that's what u wanted me to do

Comment: yes for example 5!=1*2*3*4*5

Comment: how would i do that, cuz i can only do factorial using for loops and are we allowed to use for loops in functions method

Comment: @Makoto: The algorithm seems correct. The System.out statement should probably reflect `x` rather than `number` at each iteration.

Comment: k, but when i run the code, it gets messed up, try running the code, basically i want the user to input the number between 0-10, if more, i did invalid number

Comment: The setup doesn't seem correct, though; I'd think that the `System.out.println` should be after the `for` loop. Also it's going to find the factorial of a number regardless of whether the number is greater than 10.

Comment: @TNT can u please edit the code, like edit it using mine or make a new one please?

Comment: @Monty: Try moving your `for` loop inside an `else` body of your `if`.

Comment: @Voicu what do u mean?

Comment: @Monty Think about it this way: If the number is greater than 10, print the message and do nothing else. Otherwise perform the factorial operation. So it would look like `if (number > 10) {...} else {...}`

Comment: @Voicu:  I didn't quite have my glasses on; didn't notice the reassignment there.  It definitely does look correct.

Comment: ok @TNT i will try doing what u did

Comment: @TNT, do u want me to do this (number >10) {System.out.println("Invalid!! the number has to be between 1 and 10");} else {for( int x=1; x<=number; x++ )
    { factor = factor*x;
        System.out.println("The factorial of  "+number+" is = " +factor);

Comment: @Monty Seems about right. But also include a lower bound in your condition as well so that if an inputted number falls below 0 the message will appear.

Comment: @Monty Close; just replace `&&` with `||` in your statement and it should work fine. See my answer below for clarification.

Comment: @TNT, i created a new account and i need help can u go to this link please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475089/programming-hollow-triangle-using-nested-loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int number;
System.out.println("Enter a number to find the factorial of it: ");
number= sc.nextInt();
int factor = 1;
// edit the condition so numbers that fall outside the range 0-10 will cause the error
// message to display
if (number < 1 || number > 10)
    System.out.println("Invalid!! the number has to be between 1 and 10");
else {
    for( int x=1; x<=number; x++ )
    {
        factor = factor*x;
    }
    System.out.println("The factorial of  "+number+" is = " +factor);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way i can ask a question without putting any code

Comment: Follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you should be fine.

Comment: can u just help me here? please

Comment: i have to make a program that will let teh computer randomly generate 10 marks between 0 and 100 and calculate the mean of the marks. Using functions method? How would i do that

Comment: I'll give you a few tips but won't provide a complete answer. Use `java.util.Random`'s [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) method to produce the random numbers. Create a loop that adds each random number to a variable, and then divide the value stored in the variable by 10. If you're still stuck, please ask a question and include what you've tried so far, just like you did in this question. But also add the problem that you're having, too, so that we'll know how to help you. Thanks!

Comment: TNT thanks alot man, you have been helping me alot today. Thanks man :)

Comment: how would i assign a variable? can u just give me one or two examples please. "Create a loop that adds each random number to a variable"

Comment: `int sum = 0; for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++) sum += <random number>;` Create a variable and set it equal to 0. Then at each iteration of the loop add the randomly generated number to this variable.

Comment: I left that part for you to figure out. The question is: how can you generate a pseudorandom number using `Random`'s `nextInt` method? It may take some research and experimenting, but you'll figure it out eventually!

Comment: can u explain what u mean please